# Using PhoneGap camera raises app under the device status bar

Tags: mobile, cordova

[image]

occurred on iPhone & Android both.
phoneGap 1.1.0

#### Update

My question: how can I prevent status bar cover my app. or otherwise prevent my up move up.
My Code is simple PhoneGap code:

```
 navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoSuccess, onPhotoFail, {sourceType: 0})
```

see [phoneGap api](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html)

Comment: That's an interesting observation... so what's your question?

Comment: What's your code for using the camera ?

Answer (score 0):

On android It's phonegap bug.
PhoneGap use two native plugins to activate camera:
1) camera plugin
2) status bar plugin- to hide status bar on canera state.
the issue is - when camera cancelled (after take a photo) status bar is shown but the application doesn't move down and status bar covers it.

#### update

upgarde PhoneGap version to 1.4.1 resolved the issue on android.

Comment: I'm working with PhoneGap 1.1 on iOS 5.0.1 and it works fine.

Comment: [An anonymous user comments](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/214362) that this is the solution for Android, but that the iOS problems are a different bug.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old but in case anyone finds this problem I fixed it forcing the screen size (not valid probably for the iPhone 5 screen) on the `viewDidAppearAgain` method on the view controller that inherits from `CDVViewController`.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460)];
}
```

I was using phoneGap 2.1